# WPF: How to select parent listbox if user clicked on child listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, datatemplate

In my application using DataTemplate mechanism I insert into ListBox item another listbox. But is it possible that when selected one listboxitem in parent listbox, the focus may be on another parent listboxitem's child (see picture)

[image: Pic]

How to do: if one of child listbox in focus (one item from them selected), then parent listboxitem being selected to? Using binding or templating

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NotesListBoxDataTemplate" DataType="Note">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
            <my:DatePicker Height="25" Name="datePicker1" Width="115" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit" 
                           SelectedDate="{Binding LastEdit,
                                                  Mode = TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ListBox Name="ImagesListBox"  SelectedIndex="{Binding Mode=OneWayToSource, Source={StaticResource progParameters}, Path=SelectedImage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Images}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NotesListBoxImagesTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalListBox}">
            </ListBox>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button Name="AddImageButon" Content="+" Click="AddImageButon_Click"></Button>
                <Button Name="RemoveImageButon" Content="-" Click="RemoveImageButon_Click"></Button>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the parent `ListBox` set property `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to `true`, then in the inner `ListBox`es set the `SelectedItem` property to `"{Binding SelectedItem ElementName=lbParent}"`.

Consider using a [Converter](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters) to help you get specific data that is not accessible thru xaml or if you need to do some caculations.

Hope this helps.